# react - wait for side effects to be cleaned before unmounting component

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to wait for the `useEffect` clean-up function to finish ?

```
useEffect(() => {
    return async () => {
      dialog({show: true, title: 'Cleaning up the mess. Please wait.'});

      // Start a series of long running tasks
      await system.killProcess();
      await pollUntilProcessDoesNotExist(); // Do not go anywhere until this is done

      dialog({show: false, title: undefined });      
    };
  }, [selectedSequenceId]);
```

My question comes as the result of handling state when BE tasks take long time.

In my example, we have a `system` that does long time operations. When performing a long time operation it cannot do any other one. Trying to make `system` do other stuff will come as 409 errors.
Because of this, I would like to know if we can wait until a clean-up function is done. If it is not possible, I would use a transitional route to wait in there until `system` is free.

More ideas are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you don't want to block unmounting of UI, which tells me that unmount is the incorrect dependency for the effect that you've described. What is it that causes the unmount? A back button press or something like that? That button should instead kick off the long running task and then do the navigation.

Comment: There is a selector in that page. One option is always selected. Any selection in there is doing a long time operation. Thus, instead of triggering operations every time user changes the selector, we trigger it only on exit (in the last moment). Navigating to somewhere else would trigger the long time operation.

Comment: Ah, as I expected. The unmount operation is not syntactic sugar for a "save and exit" function. You will have to intercept the exit and instead perform your "save and exit" as I mentioned above.